# How can I make my nav colors changing when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, navigation

This is what I currently have but as you can see (www.lucasdebelder.be), the nav is just hidden up until 200px after scrolling, but I kinda wanted to change it up a bit. By letting the **navigation show at start but after scrolling for let's say 200px, changing the colors** (background color and color). I will try to demonstrate what I want with a picture and example.

[So this is what it should look like upon entering on the website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbXkf.png)

[And then if you scroll down it should transform into this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3n3l.png)

This is what my jquery looks like atm.

```
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('nav').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('nav').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var size= $(".nav").offset().top;

        $(document).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > size)
            {   
               $('.nav').css({"background":"Blue"});
            } else {
               $('.nav').css({"background":"transparent"});
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can make it ease in/fade in nicely?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('nav').addClass('bg-color');
  } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('bg-color');
  }
});
```

This will add class "bg-color" in your nav after 200px scroll

Now give color to bg-color by adding this code in your css file

```
.bg-color {
  background-color:red;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! Is there anyway I can make it ease in/fade in nicely?

Comment: I tried it but it comes out a little bit wonky; http://lucasdebelder.be/nav/index.html